# (Lua 5.1) '=' expected near 'outer' | trying to execute a Lua script

Tags: lua

I am trying to get this code to work, but I don't understand why. It says that it wants an "=" to make 'goto' a variable, but it should be running a function. I am running Lua 5.1.

`ftm2mid.lua:209: '=' expected near 'outer'`

```
    local mstr = rv.frame .. ":" .. rv.row
    if loop[mstr] == setting.loops then break end
    
    for _, v in pairs(rv.lastFX) do
      if v.name == FX.HALT then
        goto outer   -- <--- Here it is
      elseif v.name == FX.SPEED then
        if v.param >= ftm.param.FxxSplit then
          if cTempo ~= v.param then newTempo = true end
          cTempo = v.param
        else...
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/67vq12Fv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to run a script designed for Lua 5.2 or newer on Lua 5.1 or older, which doesn't work. The clue is that line 209 is `goto outer`, and `goto` is new to Lua 5.2.